# History Goback is not working

Tags: javascript

I have list of products in page. And this list of products will shown only 5. After I click button 'Show extra', then it will show remaining products.

Ok after I clicked 'Show extra' button, it shows next 5 more products. so totally 8 products now. From this remaining 5 products, when I click any one product link (href), it goes to next page. The problem is, from next page when I click 'Go back' button, it is coming back to the page, but in this time, the number of products are still 5, not as 10. But I need the previous loaded products as it is how it was. If I say shortly, history goback not working.

Please suggest me.

Comment: What is happening, wehen you show the extra products? Is this a page load? Ajax?

Comment: @Anri: yes it is Ajax loading. Initially the page loaded with 5 products. After I clicked 'Show extra' button, it is showing additional 5 products. So totally in the page 10 products available. For ex, If I click 7th product, it redirected to details page. In the details page, I have Go back button to come back to the clicked product(Here 7th). But it is not coming back to 7th. Rather it goes to down of page and not showing remaining 5 products. I want that it need to be redirected to clicked product. or atleast showing the same state of 10 products.

Comment: Additional point: when I refresh the page, the same happening like remaining 5 products not loaded.

Comment: after you will reload the page the data will lost of course :) ... you can use browser storage to save loaded data number and load again same data after reload ... http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
javascript: history.go(-1)


<input type="button" value="Back" onClick="history.go(-1)">
```

> **history.back()** and **history.go(-1)** are completely identical methods. 
>   Of course history.go() can take other parms including URL's or Page
>   Titles while history.back() can only do one thing.
>
> history.previous is a property and returns the URL of the previous
>   item in the history object.
>
> var lastURL = history.previous
>
> However, this is a security issue and requires a signed script with
>   explicit permission from the visitor to successfully use
>   history.previous, .current, .next.  Unlike the history.back() and
>   history.go() methods, this one is not settable.  It's only gettable.

**after you will reload the page the data will lost of course :) ... you can use browser storage to save loaded data number and load again same data after reload ... w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp**
**enjoy :)**

Comment: what about browser back button? how dose this help him then?

Comment: yes it is Ajax loading. Initially the page loaded with 5 products. After I clicked 'Show extra' button, it is showing additional 5 products. So totally in the page 10 products available. For ex, If I click 7th product, it redirected to details page. In the details page, I have Go back button to come back to the clicked product(Here 7th). But it is not coming back to 7th. Rather it goes to down of page and not showing remaining 5 products. I want that it need to be redirected to clicked product. or atleast showing the same state of 10 products.

Answer (score 0):

`history goback` is working as expected in your example. try to avoid a `server call` when you click on `goBack button`. just do the page navigation to back

Try this one.

```
<input type="button" value="Back" onClick="history.go(-1)">
```

**OR** Try like this

```
<script>
function goBack() {
    window.history.back()
}
</script>

<body>
<button onclick="goBack()">Go Back</button>
</body>
```

Comment: yes it is Ajax loading. Initially the page loaded with 5 products. After I clicked 'Show extra' button, it is showing additional 5 products. So totally in the page 10 products available. For ex, If I click 7th product, it redirected to details page. In the details page, I have Go back button to come back to the clicked product(Here 7th). But it is not coming back to 7th. Rather it goes to down of page and not showing remaining 5 products. I want that it need to be redirected to clicked product. or atleast showing the same state of 10 products.

Comment: I think you server  call hitting when you click on back button. so the page is reloading with first 5 products. In this case use event.preventdDefault() method to stop the server call. or write a flag to send the server call

Answer (score 0):

I think the real problem here is, handling the history of your website on ajax calls. For this you could write it your self, or just read about a plugin and study it like this:

http://balupton.github.io/jquery-history/demo/

You could try it, and then come back if you have futher problems.

Hope it helps.